# How to map a nested JSON Object as an SQL table row in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I'm using Spring to develop APIs along with JPA. I'm handling a `POST` request that accepts `@RequestBody` as a JSON object that looks like this-

```
{
  "id": "323",
  "name": "Sam",
  "gpsLocation": {
    "latitude": 66.7492558,
    "longitude": 97.133258
  }
}
```

And an SQL `User` Table that has the following columns-

`id | name | latitude | longitude`

Is there a way in Spring to map this nested json object directly to these table columns?

This is what my `User.java` and `GpsLocation.java` entity classes look like right now-

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
public class UnderObservation {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String userID;

    private GpsLocation location;
}


@Entity
public class GpsLocation {

    @Column(name = "Latitude", nullable = false)
    private Double Latitude;

    @Column(name = "Longitude", nullable = false)
    private Double Longitude;

}
```

I'm looking for a way to "flatten/unwrap" `GpsLocation` class so that it directly fits into the `User` table instead of having a separate table for `GpsLocation`.

I can not change the JSON Structure because some other No SQL Databases are using this. Also, I'm new to Spring!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is using `DTO` data transfer object that hold the `request body` 
and map it to the `user` object using external library like `mapstruct`, `ObjectMapper` or even do it manually

> the DTO is a pojo Object carries data between processes

Answer (score 0):

Try This way with a **Constructor**:

```
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Table(name = "user")
        @Entity
        public class UnderObservation {

            @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
            private String name;

            @Id
            @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
            private String userID;

            @Column(name = "latitude", nullable = false)
            private Double latitude;

            @Column(name = "longitude", nullable = false)
            private Double longitude;

            private GpsLocation location;


            UnderObservation(String name, String userID, GpsLocation location) {
                this.name = name;
                this.userID = userID;
                this.location = location;

                this.latitude = this.location.getLatitude();
                this.longitude = this.location.getLongitude();
            }




        }
```

Comment: Won't work in spring, since it maps using noArgs constructor and setters.